# parachainSystem.ValidationFunctionStored

Tags: parachain, runtime-upgrade, upgrade, parachain-system

The validation function has been scheduled to apply.
What does this event mean?
[image]

When my upgrade will be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means the upgrade has been scheduled. You can see when the upgrade will take place by checking the [`FutureCodeUpgrade(id)` storage item](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/15709ee/runtime/parachains/src/paras/mod.rs#L615) on the Relay Chain.